# project xxxx is associated to an unknown SonarQube server(). Please fix project association or add server in SonarQube plugin perfrences

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, jakarta-ee

When I open any java class in eclipse editor it is showing below popup message.

[image]

Comment: Have you tried doing what it says to do in the popup?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right click your project and choose `SonarQube`. then click on `Remove the SonarQube server nature`

**EDIT**

Another option is to go to `Windows` -> `Preferences` -> `SonarQube` -> `Server` and to remove or fix your server here.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but i don't see any edit or remove button in Sonar node Dialog

Comment: thanks for your answer, issue is fixed bit changes in your answer

Answer (score 1):

**Another solution:**

I had two Sonar-PlugIns (SonarQube and SonarLint). The first posted solution has't worked for me. But the following had worked: in eclipse installation directory, open the file:

```
<yourEclipseInstallDirectory>\configuration\customization.ini
```

And delete what is after the `=` sign.

```
org.sonar.ide.eclipse.core/servers/default/url=<deleteWhatIsHere>
```